# How to pass a solution into an model as a fixed start in docplex?

Tags: docplex

I have two models: an initial model and a more complex model with more decision variables. I need to use the solution to the first model as a fixed start for the second model but can't figure out a way to do this automatically. The decision variables are a mix of integer, binary and continuous variables, and the initial solution values must be unchanged in the second model, so I can't use a warm start. What would be the best way to do this? Is there another way to read the starting solution from a .mst file as a fixed start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is transferring a solution from one model to another instance.
Assuming variables in both models have same name, have a look at `Model.import_solution` with match='name'.
See doc here :
http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.model.html#docplex.mp.model.Model.import_solution

Once imported to the second model, use the imported solution as a MIP start with `Model.add_mip_start`,
adjust which variables are fixed with the `write_levelè parameter.

By default, only discrete variables are fixed.